# ZF2 - How to add a new Form in an existing Controller?

Tags: php, forms, controller, zend-framework2

I have a login Form `LoginForm.php` with its Filter `LoginFilter.php`, that has a View `/login/index.phtml`, a Controller `LoginController.php`, two Factory `LoginControllerFactory.php` & `LoginFormFactory.php` and it is called in the `config.module.php` and works perfect. The Form is correctly displayed.

I have a `ViewController.php` that has a method `idAction` that shows a post by its `id` passed by parameter from the homepage in a View called `/view/id.phtml`. I want to display this Form I created within this View and I don't know how. First, I created the Form exactly as I created the login Form, but I realized that I already configured my `id` child-route, inside of `view` route with a Factory in `module.config.php`.

Then, I tried to set the form in the `idAction` method, exactly as I did in `indexAction` in `LoginController.php` Controller, but I'm receiving the following error: `An exception was raised while creating "Rxe\Factory\ViewController"; no instance returned`.

I will now show you what I did to try to display this new Form.

First, the Form itself:

```
class CommentForm extends Form
{
    public function buildForm()
    {
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'POST');
        $this->setAttribute('id', 'add-comment-form');
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'comment',
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Category'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-success',
                'value' => 'Comment'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Form's `CommentFormFactory.php` calling its Filter and building the Form:

```
class CommentFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $form = new CommentForm();
        $form->setInputFilter($serviceLocator->get('Rxe\Factory\CommentFilter'));
        $form->buildForm();

        return $form;
    }
}
```

The `ViewControllerFactory.php` calling the `CommentFormFactory.php`, just like in `LoginControllerFactory.php`:

```
class ViewControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        $viewController = new ViewController();
        $viewController->setPostsTable($serviceManager->get('Rxe\Factory\PostsTable'));
        $viewController->setCommentsTable($serviceManager->get('Rxe\Factory\CommentsTable'));
        $viewController->setCommentForm($serviceManager->get('Rxe\Factory\CommentForm'));

        return $viewController;
    }
}
```

The `ViewController.php`, calling the form within its `idAction`'s `ViewModel`:

```
class ViewController extends AbstractActionController
{
    use PostsTableTrait;
    use CommentsTableTrait;

    private $commentForm;

    function setCommentForm($commentForm)
    {
        $this->commentForm = $commentForm;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $category = $this->params()->fromRoute('category');

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'posts' => $this->postsTable->getPostsByCategory($category),
            'categories' => $category
        ));
    }

    public function idAction()
    {
        $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

        $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
            'commentForm' => $this->commentForm,
            'commentParams' => $this->params()->fromPost(),
            'messages' => $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages(),
            'posts' => $this->postsTable->getPostById($id),
            'posts' => $this->commentsTable->getNumberOfCommentsByPost($id),
            'comments' => $this->commentsTable->getCommentsByPost($id)
        ));
        $viewModel->setTemplate('rxe/view/id.phtml');

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $this->commentForm->setData($this->params()->fromPost());

            if ($this->commentForm->isValid()) {
                $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Thank you for your comment. :)');
            } else {
                $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Your comment wasn\'t sent.');
            }
        }

        return $viewModel;
    }
}
```

And finally my `module.config.php`

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Rxe\Controller\Index' => 'Rxe\Controller\IndexController',
        'Rxe\Controller\View' => 'Rxe\Controller\ViewController',
        'Rxe\Controller\Login' => 'Rxe\Controller\LoginController'
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'Rxe\Factory\LoginController' => 'Rxe\Factory\LoginControllerFactory',
        'Rxe\Factory\ViewController' => 'Rxe\Factory\ViewControllerFactory',
        'Rxe\Factory\IndexController' => 'Rxe\Factory\IndexControllerFactory'
    )
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Rxe\Factory\LoginForm' => 'Rxe\Factory\LoginFormFactory',
        'Rxe\Factory\LoginFilter' => 'Rxe\Factory\LoginFilterFactory',
        'Rxe\Factory\CommentForm' => 'Rxe\Factory\CommentFormFactory',
        'Rxe\Factory\CommentFilter' => 'Rxe\Factory\CommentFilterFactory',
        'Rxe\Factory\PostsTable' => 'Rxe\Factory\PostsTableFactory',
        'Rxe\Factory\CategoriesTable' => 'Rxe\Factory\CategoriesTableFactory',
        'Rxe\Factory\CommentsTable' => 'Rxe\Factory\CommentsTableFactory',
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterService' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'
    )
),
```

Please, let me know if you need me to show you more codes. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT #1**

If I remove the line that calls the Form in the `ViewControllerFactory.php`, I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/vol12_3/byethost4.com/b4_16354889/htdocs/module/Rxe/view/rxe/view/id.phtml on line 31`

The `id.phtml` is:

```
<!-- Comment form -->
<div id="comment-form-area" class="col-xs-3">
    <?php $this->commentForm->prepare() ?>
    <?php echo $this->form()->openTag($this->commentForm); ?>
    <div class="form-group comment-area">
        <?php echo $this->formRow($this->commentForm->get('comment_content')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $this->formRow($this->commentForm->get('submit')); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
</div>
<!-- /Comment form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing these lines

```
'invokables' => array(
    'Rxe\Controller\Index' => 'Rxe\Controller\IndexController',
    'Rxe\Controller\View' => 'Rxe\Controller\ViewController',
    'Rxe\Controller\Login' => 'Rxe\Controller\LoginController'
),
```

If it doesn't work, have a look at this tutorial how to create proper controller factories and pass dependencies. https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/zend-framework-2-using-__invokepluginmanager-manager-in-services-factory/

An example how I build my forms:

```
namespace Admin\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class ContentForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("content");
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'name' => 'title',
            'attributes' => [
                'required'   => true,
                'size'        => 40,
                'id'         => "seo-caption",
                'placeholder' => 'Title',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Title',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'name' => 'text',
            'attributes' => [
                'class'   => 'ckeditor',
                'rows'        => 5,
                'cols'      => 80,
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Text',
            ],
        ]);

    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            [
                "name"=>"title",
                "required" => true,
                'filters' => [
                    ['name' => 'StripTags'],
                    ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty'],
                    [
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => [
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 1,
                            'max' => 200,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                "name"=>"text",
                "required" => true,
                'filters' => [
                    ['name' => 'StripTags'],
                    ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty'],
                    [
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => [
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Than I create a Factory
namespace Admin\Factory\Controller;

```
use Admin\Controller\ContentController;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager;

class ContentFormFactory
{
    /**
     * @{inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __invoke(ControllerManager $controllerManager)
    {
        return new ContentController(
            $controllerManager->getServiceLocator()->get('FormElementManager')->get('Admin\Form\ContentForm')
        );
    }
}
```

Inside module.config.php I have this code

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Admin\Controller\Content' => "Admin\Factory\Controller\ContentFormFactory",
    ],
    'invokables' => [
        ...
    ],
],
```

Please, show us some more code.

Comment: Creating a Form isn't the problem but how to call it within an existing Controller, like my `ViewController.php` that already has other things, instead of creating a separated one for the Form.

Comment: I put my `id.phtml` part where I call the Form to be shown, and the error I get if I remove the line that calls for my Form in the `ViewControllerFactory.php`

Comment: I really don't think that the way you are creating the form is correct. Please, refer to the docs http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html since from what I see your form isn't returning an instance and that's why you get the first error.

Comment: Well, the way I did for the Login worked perfectly, but it has its own Controller and ControllerFactory. The Comment I want to make I don't know what to do with them, since I want to call it from an existing Controller, which is View. Do I really need a Controller? Where and how do I call it? That's my problem.

Comment: Create a factory for the CommentForm and pass it via the Controller constructor method. After that in your module.config.php file move the controller in the factories array.

Comment: No matter what I do I keep receiving the error `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`. I already have a Factory, but I don't know how to call for it differently.